# Finding id with jQuery in a th:each

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, bootstrap-modal

**Hello guys**, I have a list of divs made with th:each (spring) in my HTML. And I have to select a button of this specific that open a bootstrap-modal, in this modal, the values of the selected item should be displayed, but I can't pick up from its id from th:each.

The HTML:

```
<div th:each="object : ${objects}">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="width: 0 auto">
        <div class="box-sombra">
            <h3 class="box-titulo" th:text="${object.someField}"></h3>
                <div class="box-conteudo">
                    <p th:text="${object.someField1}"></p>
                    <p th:text="${object.someField2}"></p>
                </div>
                <p class="box-botoes">
                    <a th:id="${object.id}" 
                       role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit
                    </a>
                </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should post your html / relevent code, that way it will be more easy for members of SO to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I already got my solution, just take the value from the button whom calls the modal, then I can manipulate in my js.

The Javascript:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
    var recipient = button.val(); //The ID of object : )

    console.log("The ID from th:each is: ", recipient); 

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit selector. If you post your code maybe we can help much

```
var yourSelector = $("#myTable thead th");
//if the TH has an ID
yourSelector.each(function(){
    console.log($(this).closest("[id]").attr("id"))
});

//if hasnt
yourSelector.each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("id"))
});
```